# OpenID-like solution for native iOS client and WCF back-end?

Tags: ios, wcf, authentication, oauth, openid

OpenID allows users to sign in/sign up web-sites by asking their OpenID providers to provide a sort of specific GUID for single user for single realm.

Let's say, the client is native iOS and back-end is RESTful WCF service.

The question:

Is there a similar solution for the case when I need to allow native mobile client application users access my web service by authenticating against Google/Facebook?

I've read about OAuth, but frankly I didn't get whether it suits my case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OATH authentication explanation in [this](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/8237/is-there-any-drawback-of-using-oauth-pseudoauthentication-as-opposed-to-openid) might somewhat clear your doubt about what to choose.